# Checking my vmnic on ESXi server using Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to Checking my vmnic on ESXi server.

Let me show my Ansible-playbook yaml code, it's very simple.

```
---
- hosts: host
  vars:
    vcenter_server: "192.168.35.219"
    vcenter_user: "root"
    vcenter_pass: "P@ssw0rd"
    esxi_hostname: "esxihost1"
  gather_facts: true


  - name: Gather info about vmnics of an ESXi Host
    community.vmware.vmware_host_vmnic_info:
      hostname: '{{ vcenter_server }}'
      username: '{{ vcenter_user }}'
      password: '{{ vcenter_pass }}'
      esxi_hostname: '{{ esxi_hostname }}'
      validate_certs: no
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: host_vmnics

  - name: print esxi info
    ansible.builtin.debug: 
      var: host_vmnics.hosts_vmnics_info.esxihost1.vmnic_details
```

I want  display vmnic status using Ansible playbook.

I created a playbook as below and ran it.
However, it contains a lot of unnecessary information.

```
TASK [Gather info about vmnics of an ESXi Host] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.35.219 -> localhost]

TASK [print esxi info] ************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.35.219] => {
    "host_vmnics.hosts_vmnics_info.esxihost1.vmnic_details": [
        {
            "actual_duplex": "Full Duplex",
            "actual_speed": 10000,
            "adapter": "VMware Inc. vmxnet3 Virtual Ethernet Controller",
            "configured_duplex": "Full Duplex",
            "configured_speed": 10000,
            "device": "vmnic0",
            "driver": "nvmxnet3",
            "lldp_info": "N/A",
            "location": "0000:0b:00.0",
            "mac": "00:0c:29:bc:67:65",
            "status": "Connected"
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want to see `actual_duplex`,`actual_speed`,`device`,`status`

like below

```
    "host_vmnics.hosts_vmnics_info.esxihost1.vmnic_details": [
        {
            "actual_duplex": "Full Duplex",
            "actual_speed": 10000,
            "device": "vmnic0",
            "status": "Connected"
        }
    ]
}
```

And, `actual duplex: Full Duplex` `actual speed: 10000`, `device: vmnic0`, `status: Connected` If each value is correct, "OK"

If not, I want to display it as "NOTOK".

Is it possible?

Comment: [Same comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74859989/checking-my-vmnic-on-esxi-server-using-ansible), on what criteria are OK or NOK based? Do you hold a dictionary with the OK values?

Comment: Um... I think so.
 For example when querying ESXi , If the vmnic is not "status: Connected", "NOT OK" is output.


I want to do something similar with a shell script.
if [[ "foo" == "$var" ]]; Then
OK
else
Not OK
fi

Comment: Then your immediate first step is to construct this dictionary/reference of what should be the OK values and add this to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding

> *it contains a lot of unnecessary information*

you may have a look into the general documentation about Ansible [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html)

> *Ansible modules normally return a data structure that can be registered into a variable, or seen directly when output by the ansible program.*

and because of

> *Each module can optionally document its own unique return values*

into the specific documentation about [`vmware_host_vmnic_info` module - Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_host_vmnic_info_module.html#return-values).

> *dict with hostname as key and dict with vmnics information as value*

In other words, the data structure `hosts_vmnics_info` returned just contain all this `vmnic_details`.

---

Regarding

> *I only want to see `actual_duplex`, `actual_speed`, `device`, `status`*

you can access the key values by using in example something like

```yaml
- name: Show
  debug:
    msg: "Device {{ host_vmnics.hosts_vmnics_info.esxihost1.vmnic_details[0].device }} is in status {{ host_vmnics.hosts_vmnics_info.esxihost1.vmnic_details[0].status }} at an actual speed of {{ host_vmnics.hosts_vmnics_info.esxihost1.vmnic_details[0].actual_speed }} in mode {{ 
host_vmnics.hosts_vmnics_info.esxihost1.vmnic_details[0].actual_duplex }}"
```

**Further Documenation**

- [Using Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html)
- [Referencing list variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-list-variables)
- [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables)

---

Regarding

> *If the vmnic is not `status: Connected`, "NOT OK" is output. I want to do something similar a shell script `if [[ "foo" == "$var" ]]; Then OK else Not OK fi`*

you could use an approach with the [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html) module like

```yaml
- name: Check connection status
  ansible.builtin.assert:
    that:
      - "host_vmnics.hosts_vmnics_info.esxihost1.vmnic_details[0].status == 'Connected'"
    fail_msg: "NOT OK"
    success_msg: "OK"
```